# Implicit not found while it's presented in the scope

Tags: scala, typeclass, implicit

Consider the following example:

```
sealed trait ST

object ST{
  case class ST1() extends ST
  case class ST2() extends ST
}

trait TypeClass[A]{
  def doSome(a: A): Unit
}

case class Test[T](t: T)

implicit val tp: TypeClass[Test[_ <: ST]] = ???  //the implicit

def foo[A: TypeClass](a: A) = implicitly[TypeClass[A]].doSome(a)

val v: Test[_ <: ST] = ???

foo(v) //error: implicit not found
```

[**SCASTIE**](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/FAAfivTZSv2E1cq5ETbYsw)

As can be seen the required implicit is in scope while it is not recognized by the compile.

Why does that happen and is there a workaround to call `foo`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Existential types are not inferred during implicit resolution so `f(v)` fails because it is looking for an implicit value with non-inferred type

```
TypeClass[Test[_$4]]]
                |
          existential not inferred
```

however whey you explicitly provide the type variable instance `foo[Test[_ <: ST]](v)` then implicit resolution should work because we are past inference stage.

It works in Scala 3 probably because internally it [rewrites](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/dropped-features/existential-types.html) existential types to refined types.

Answer (score 5):

If you change `foo(v)` to `foo(v)(tp)` it'll explain (a little bit) better why it doesn't want to use tp.

In a nutshell, `def foo[A : TypeClass]` wants an implicit of type `TypeClass[A]`.
When you do `foo(v)`, A becomes `Test[_ <: ST]` which means "`Test` of some *specific* but unknown subtype of `ST`". So, `foo` wants an implicit for *that* specific type.

But `tp` is *not that*. It is a "TypeClass for `Test` or *any* subclass of `ST`" (apparently `_` means slightly different things in these two contexts, because `v` is a concrete instance, that must have a *specific* type).

Long story short, `Test[_ <: ST]` is *not* the actual type of `v`, but a *supertype* of its type. So, to make it work, you just need to make the `TypeClass` contravariant (`TypeClass[-A]`) - that'll make `foo` accept `tp` as the implicit, because its type will be a subtype of what it expects.

Comment: How about the thing that calling `foo[Test[_ <: ST]](v)` works as expected?

Comment: @SomeName here you are "casting" `v` from "Test of some specific, but unknown subclass of `ST`" to it's supertype "Test of any subclass of `ST`", and that works, because an implicit `TypeClass` of _that_ type (`tp`) is in scope.